# How can I exclude some records in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, database

here is my problem... sorry if it's too simple for some users, I'm a newbie at this.

I have three DB tables, **People**(idPerson), **Question**(idQuestion,Answer), **AskedQuestions**(idPerson,idQuestion). When I ask a question to a user, i add a row to AskedQuestions so i can have the registry.

The problem I have is that I  have to select a **random** question, which wasnt asked before to a specified user.

I've been reading for hours for the best way to select random rows, and separately how to make a query to select only the asked ones, but havent figured how can I mix them.

Anyone knows how can I do it, in **PHP and MySql**? I'll apreciate it very much.
Thanks to the community in advance, and sorry for my english, my english skills are not the best!

Greetings

**EDIT**

I tried to vote all of u up, but I can't until I have rep15, ahahhaa... I forgot to metion one thing, as I was reading, using RAND() makes a full scan of the table, which in my case is unacceptable because the tables are pretty big Questions about 500000 records and AskedQuestions something about a 1500000 or even more... so the times that takes doing the RAND are tooo slow...

I need something like... join the questions and asked questions and exluding the ones that have the idUser equal to the session user and the idQuestion == idAskedQuestion... and the select a random one from there?

Is there a way to do that, and in that case, It will be horribly slow??

Comment: Show, what you have tried so far.

Comment: @djot I know how to obtain a random row from the DB, by finding the number of rows, using php to find a random number between 0 and the COUNT, and then fetching the row with the random id generated.

But when I add the restriction of only get the non-asked questions... everything gets more complicated, I cant do that procedure because not all the questions should be aviable.

Comment: @djot
And the other problem is that I think I should use some kind of JOIN, but not certain how, I have almost no knowledge in DataBases.

If you think i didnt do anything and just came to ask, thats ok! I dont want a written code answer, I'm happy with some words an explanation!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$res=mysql_query("select count(*) as number from question where idquestion not 
in(select idquestion from askedquestion where idperson='".$_session['id']."')");
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$num=$row['number'];
//$num has no. of rows

$final_query="select * from question where idquestion 
not in(select idquestion from askedquestion 
where idperson='".$_session['id']."') limit ".rand(0,$num).",1";
```

It will select different question

Comment: I can also do it using left join if you want then i can show you

Comment: Are you using session variables or not

Comment: Yes, I use session variables! But I dont want to use RAND because my tables are too big, and it takes too much time! I edited the post to reflect some kind of suggestion of how i was thinking on doing it

Comment: I think im loving you, hahahah... Thanks!! I'll try this one

Answer (score 1):

select random questions:

```
select * from question order by rand() limit 1
```

Select questions not asked before:

```
select * from question where idQuestion not in (select idQuestion from AskedQuestions)
```

combined:

```
select * from question 
where idQuestion not in (select idQuestion from AskedQuestions)
order by rand() 
limit 1
```

Comment: he does not want the question which are in asked question

Comment: Now you have not ordered it randomly

Comment: @Webtecher: It is randomly ordered in the combined query.

Comment: Hey guys! Thanks for the quick answer! ... As I told webtecher in the prvious answer I dont want to use RAND because my tables are too big, and it takes too much time! I edited the post to reflect some kind of suggestion of how i was thinking on doing it

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried `ORDER BY RAND()` to select random rows, and `NOT IN` to match only not asked questions?
Something like:

```
SELECT q.idQuestion
FROM Question q
WHERE q.idQuestion NOT IN (SELECT aq.idQuestion FROM AskedQuestions aq WHERE aq.idPerson = 1)
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Obviously, replace 1 by the appropriate value (probably a PHP variable).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer to you too! ... As I told the others in the previous answers I dont want to use RAND because my tables are too big, and it takes too much time! I edited the post to reflect some kind of suggestion of how i was thinking on doing it

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT * FROM Question, AskedQuestions WHERE AskedQuestions.idQuestion != Question.idQuestion AND AskedQuestions.idPerson = 'PERSON_ID' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer to you too! ... As I told the others in the previous answers I dont want to use RAND because my tables are too big, and it takes too much time! I edited the post to reflect some kind of suggestion of how i was thinking on doing it

Comment: Ok. Good to know. But you should use JOINs instead of IN-statements. In-statement subquery selects all records in subtable for every row, so avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Try query given below

```
SELECT * FROM `Question` AS qs WHERE qs.idQuestion not in(SELECT aq.idQuestion FROM  
   AskedQuestions` AS aq WHERE aq.idPerson = loggedinUserID) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1
```

If You not want to use rand() in query then there is one way for it..

```
   /*Select max and min id*/
   $range_result = mysql_query( " SELECT MAX(`idQuestion `) AS max_id , MIN(`idQuestion `) AS 
   min_id FROM `Question` ");

    $range_row = mysql_fetch_object( $range_result );

    $random = mt_rand( $range_row->min_id , $range_row->max_id );

   $result = mysql_query( " SELECT * FROM `Question` AS qs  WHERE qs.`idQuestion` >= $random  
    AND qs.idQuestion not in (SELECT aq.idQuestion From ASkedQuestions AS aq where  
    aq.idPerson   = loggedInUSerID) LIMIT 0,1 ");
```

I hope it will be helpful for you.

thanks

thanks

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer to you too! ... As I told the others in the previous answers I dont want to use RAND because my tables are too big, and it takes too much time! I edited the post to reflect some kind of suggestion of how i was thinking on doing it

Answer (score 0):

What have you done so far?

you could try this:

```
SELECT * Question q LEFT JOIN AskedQuestions a ON a.idQuestion = q.idQuestion WHERE a.idQuestion is null AND a.id AND a.idperson = 2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer to you too! ... As I told the others in the previous answers I dont want to use RAND because my tables are too big, and it takes too much time! I edited the post to reflect some kind of suggestion of how i was thinking on doing it

Answer (score 0):

I have made a survey of how to pick random rows *efficiently*.  The results are [*here*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/techniques-on-efficiently-finding-a-random-row/).

For your case, do you have an `AUTO_INCREMENT`?  If so, then see if "Case: AUTO_INCREMENT with gaps, 1 row returned" will satisfy your need.  Note that the `WHERE` clause to filter out unwanted questions leads to "gaps".

If not, then consider the FLOAT or UUID approaches.  Either should do nicely, but probably requires a column for this "random" purpose.